# How to disable excel cannot empty the clipboard(without killing remote desktop program)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Currently i am using Excel 2007 and using Teamviewer to control remote PC and also using Mouse Without BOrders, because i am using 2 pc.

Question is, is there a way to disable "cannot empty clipboard"?

I've come across this thread:
[How do I get rid of the "cannot empty the clipboard" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928274/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-cannot-empty-the-clipboard-error)
But the solutions is to kill teamviewer or any other program that sharing clipboard.

I need those programs running, so i guess i need to disable the warning. How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?  The obvious solution would be to not use the clipboard.

Comment: what code?                                                                                                        I'm aware that the solution is not to use the clipboard. But, 50% of my job is to copy paste things, including from one pc to another.

Comment: So i guess there is something like disabling the registry or something?